# Google Maps API setBounds of object

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I **set** the bounds of an existing object (Like a ground overlay, rectangle, etc.) in Google Maps API v3?

For example:

```
// Assuming a map and a rectangle have already been created.

var newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-20,-10),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50,30)
);
rectangle.setBounds(newBounds);
```

Is there an equivalent to `setBounds()`?

Note: I could change the recangle's bounds array directly, but as Google keeps changing their variable keys for bounds this would eventually break the script.

Comment: For which object do you want to set bounds? Map has `fitBounds()`, rectangle has `setBounds()`. Circle doesn't have it but is there need for  it? GroundsOverlay: again `fitBounds` if map is defined. Autocomplete and SearchBox have `setBounds`.

Comment: I want to set the bounds for a GroundOverlay. However, `fitBounds()` is not a valid method for the `GroundOverlay` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by taking a look at the `GroundOverlay` constructor:

```
var groundOverlay = ...

var newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-20,-10),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50,30)
);

groundOverlay.set("bounds",newBounds);
groundOverlay.map_changed();
```

Answer (score 0):

If - for any reason - you should be interested in having the values to store them and have them assigned to your own key specification (avoiding the problem of google changing the keys of the object) you can use the .toString() function. Working for both, bounds or coordinates objects.